# Openpyxl - Error loading workbook with conditional formatting

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, conditional-formatting

First time making a question here. I am learning Python and I've encountered a problem with my last code. For reference, I'm using the 3.6 version and everything was installed in the last weeks, so should be updated.

When I try to open an .xlsm file with Openpyxl I get the error pasted bellow. After removing the Conditional Formatting from the workbook, everything works as expected. It also worked when using Pandas.

I have used the module with other files before without a problem. I've found a few similar questions but usually much older and supposedly corrected in older patches. The code snippet should just build the file path and worked with other files. Any lights on this?

```
    import openpyxl

    Ano = '-2018'
    arquivo = 'Controle de Produção v2 '
    arquivo = arquivo + dataEx[3:]+ '-' + Ano[3:] 
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Dropbox\\Produção Equipes\\"+arquivo+".xlsx")
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 57, in _convert
    value = expected_type(value) ValueError: could not convert string to float: '$G$16-0.015'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Desktop\Documents\Hugo\Python\Projetos\Produtividade\Produtividade.py", line 33, in <module>
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Dropbox\\Produção Equipes\\"+arquivo+".xlsx", False, True) #DEFINIR CAMINHO COMPLETO   File "C:\Users\Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 245, in load_workbook
    ws_parser.parse()   File "C:\Users\Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py", line 127, in parse
    dispatcher[tag_name](element)   File "C:\Users\Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py", line 286, in parser_conditional_formatting
    cf = ConditionalFormatting.from_tree(element)   File "C:\Users\Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 79, in from_tree
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)   File "C:\Users\Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 79, in from_tree
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)   File "C:\Users\Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 79, in from_tree
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)   File "C:\Users\Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 92, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)   File "C:\Users\Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\formatting\rule.py", line 60, in __init__
    self.val = val   File "C:\Users\Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\formatting\rule.py", line 39, in __set__
    super(ValueDescriptor, self).__set__(instance, value)   File "C:\Users\Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 69, in __set__
    value = _convert(self.expected_type, value)   File "C:\Users\Desktop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 59, in _convert
    raise TypeError('expected ' + str(expected_type)) TypeError: expected <class 'float'>
```

Comment: As I said, first time asking a question and begginer coder in Python. Feel free to give any feedback on those issues as well.

Comment: How does cell G16 looks like in your worksheet? Maybe you can make a print-screen of the worksheet if you are allowed to.

Comment: I suggest you submit a bug report on the openpyxl tracker including a sample file. The exception itself is pretty clear but it's not really resolvable without the file.

Comment: @Elmex80s The cell itself is in the time format **hh:mm** but the error refers to the formula used in conditional formatting `=$G$16-0,015` It subtracts around 20 minutes from the time in cell G16.

Comment: @Charlie I will submit a bug report if there are no other answers for this problem. Similar problems were solved in earlier patches, maybe it's just a simple mistake.

Comment: I have found a similar issue here: [BitBucket Issue #849](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/849/849-type-error-when-loading-excel-with) but I don't know how to implement the sollution...

Answer (score 1):

Well, not an definite answer but the program was able to fully run after commenting the lines:

```
def parser_conditional_formatting(self, element):
          None #CHANGED FOR PRODUTIVIDADE.PY
##        cf = ConditionalFormatting.from_tree(element)
##        for rule in cf.rules:
##            if rule.dxfId is not None:
##                rule.dxf = self.differential_styles[rule.dxfId]
##            self.ws.conditional_formatting.add(cf.sqref, rule)
```

in **openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py**.

I know this is not really a sollution but at least the program is loading the workbook. I will try to submit an issue in BitBucket for a better analysis.